# How can I receive Chrome notifications for web applications like Messenger, Telegram or Skype?

Tags: google-chrome, notifications, facebook-messenger, skype-for-web, telegram

**Background:**

I use Chrome to access web applications like *messenger.com*, *web.telegram.org* or *web.skype.com*. For all these, I enabled Chrome's notifications.

**Question:**

How can I see these desktop notifications without having the aforementioned applications actively opened in a tab?

Comment: Those need to be coded by the respective website developers..

Comment: I see, thanks! So nothing the user can do himself.